# How to select few rows having duplicate entries?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT cat.category, cr.course, subcat.subcategory, vd.video_title, vd.video_length, vd.video_id
    FROM category As cat
    INNER JOIN subcategory as subcat 
    ON cat.parent_id=subcat.parent_id
    INNER JOIN courses As cr
    ON cr.child_id=subcat.child_id
    INNER JOIN video_details AS vd
    ON vd.course_id=cr.course_id
    WHERE cat.category='Engineering'
```

This query returns all the entries in videos_details table matching with category but
the requirement is to fetch only first five entries from video_details table for each subcategory, of category in where clause.

The structure is like this
For each category there are multiple subcategories
and for each subcategories there are multiple courses
for each courses there are multiple video records.

The above query will have multiple duplicate values in subcategory column, so how can I get only five rows of each duplicate value?

Answer (score 0):

The `LIMIT` keyword can be used to get just the first 5 (or 10 or whatever) rows from a query, so if I understand your requirements correctly you can change the `INNER JOIN` on `video_details` to an `INNER JOIN` on a *subquery* of `video_details` that will get just the first 5 rows.

Will this work for you? The change is on the third-to-last line:

```
SELECT cat.category, cr.course, subcat.subcategory, vd.video_title, vd.video_length, vd.video_id
  FROM category As cat
  INNER JOIN subcategory as subcat 
  ON cat.parent_id=subcat.parent_id
  INNER JOIN courses As cr
  ON cr.child_id=subcat.child_id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT course FROM video_details LIMIT 5) vd
  ON vd.course_id=cr.course_id
  WHERE cat.category='Engineering'
```